# Android XMLWise Reading Plist from Resource Folder

Tags: android

I have a question about XMLWise. I would like to read the following plist file in my resource folder (R.raw.key_text.plist)

```
<dict>
   <key> 551 </key>
   <string> Hello World </ string>
   ....
</dict>
```

And for my java:

```
Map<String, Object> properties = Plist.load(/*What do I put in here*/);
```

I've searched online, but can't seem to find a conclusion. I would like to print they key next to the string beside it.

Help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Put your plist in there.

```
Map<String, Object> properties = Plist.load("R.raw.key_text.plist");
```

Comment: I couldn't get that to work.... see my answer to this on SO here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15180821/android-cannot-find-plist-in-res-raw-using-xmlwise