# Android: Cannot find plist in res/raw using xmlwise

Tags: android, xml-parsing, plist

I am trying to read a plist into my android app using xml wise. This is my code

```
String path = "android.resource://" + context.getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.nameofplist;
Map<String, Object> males = Plist.load(path);
```

But i keep getting:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /android.resource:/com.packagename.appname/2130968577 (No such file or directory)
```

What is the proper way to get the path to my plist `nameofplist.plist` in my `res/raw` folder?

Answer (score 9):

I struggled to find an answer to this too... but I worked it out eventually.

Here's my solution based on a plist file called **airports.plist** sitting in the res/raw folder.

```
Map<String, Object> properties = null;
try {
    InputStream inputStream =getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.airports);
    BufferedReader br = null;
    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }
        properties = Plist.fromXml(sb.toString());

        //TODO do something with the object here
        System.out.println("plist object... "+properties);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        br.close();
    }
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Hope this helps someone!